# What is the meaning of these features of Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I want to know the meaning following features of Twitter -

```
'fast_followers_count', 'normal_followers_count'
```

I require this information for some research purpose.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an undocumented API value and there is no programming question here.

Answer (score 2):

This is an undocumented feature. It does not appear on the [user object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object) page.

You only get this information if you have retrieved data using the official Twitter API keys.

As far as I can tell, "fast" followers means "recent followers". The sum of fast and normal should give you the total count.

This is just speculation. It is an undocumented feature and shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: Correct, these values are not part of the Twitter API and should not be used.

You can read more about "fast follow" here https://blog.twitter.com/en_us/a/2010/introducing-fast-follow-and-other-sms-tips.html